# How to do two replacements using one regex statement in vim

Tags: regex, vim

If I have

```
/*... code ...*/
lord
Lord
/*... code ...*/
```

I want a regex to consider the case of the first letter and based on that makes the change. Basically, I want the above lines to change to

```
/*... code ...*/
cord
Cord
/*... code ...*/
```

In Vim I have tried something, but I know it is not going to work

```
s/[l|L]ord/(/*what should i write here*/)rod/gc
```

PS: I know I can do it in tow steps but I thought it is possible to do it in just one step

Comment: You may do it in Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew however, I am not going to switch my editor just to do this find and replace.

Comment: Sure, no need to if you already figured out a work around.

Comment: `:%s/lord/cord/g | %s/Lord/Cord/g`